# if the key does not exists return the key itself php

Tags: php, arrays

here is my code
i want it to if the statment does not exists return the key value
like 'something' in last line of code but it's not working

```
function getTranslation($translations, $lang, $statement)
{
    $lang = $translations[$lang];
    $statement = $lang[$statement];
    return $statment;
}

$translations = [
    'fa' => ['Hello!' => 'hi!', 'Hi!' => 'hi!'],
    'fr' => ['Hello!' => 'Bonjour!']
];

echo getTranslation($translations, 'fa', 'Hi!');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getTranslation($translations, 'fr', 'Hello!');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getTranslation($translations, 'fr', 'Something');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the null [coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) `??` (introduced in PHP 7) to say if the array element doesn't exist, then return a default value - in this case `$statement`...

```
function getTranslation($translations, $lang, $statement)
{
    $lang = $translations[$lang];
    return $lang[$statement] ?? $statement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getTranslation($translations, $lang, $statement)
{
    $lang = $translations[$lang];

    //check if $statement key does not exist in $lang
    if(!array_key_exists($statement, $lang)) {

        //array key does not exist, return $statement
        return $statement;
    }

    //array key always exists, so return translated value
    return $lang[$statement];
}
```

You could shorten this a bit using a ternary.

```
function getTranslation($translations, $lang, $statement)
{
    $lang = $translations[$lang];
    return array_key_exists($statement, $lang) ? $lang[$statement] : $statement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read about the basic operator `isset` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Your code will look like this:

```php
function getTranslation($translations, $lang, $statement)
{
    if (!isset($translations[$lang])) { // checking that "translation catalogue" exist
        return null; // consider throwing an exception if translation is missing 
    }
    
    $catalogue = $translations[$lang]; // saving it into variable
    
    if (!isset($catalogue[$statement])) { // checking that "word" exists in catalogue
        return $statement; // if it does not exist return requested "word"
    }
    
    return $catalogue[$statement]; // otherwise return "translated word"
}

$translations = [
    'fa' => ['Hello!' => 'hi!', 'Hi!' => 'hi!'],
    'fr' => ['Hello!' => 'Bonjour!']
];

echo getTranslation($translations, 'fa', 'Hi!');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getTranslation($translations, 'fr', 'Hello!');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getTranslation($translations, 'fr', 'Something');
```